# How to provide input layer to tf.layers.Conv3D?

Tags: python, tensorflow

tf.layers have two classes for 3d convolution. 1) tf.layers.conv3d and 2) tf.layers.Conv3D

According to the documentation, tf.layers.conv3d is going to be deprecated. So I started using tf.layers.Conv3D.

But tf.layers.Conv3D doesn't have a parameter to specify the input layer where as tf.layers.conv3d has.

Can someone help me figure out how to give inputs to tf.layers.Conv3D layer ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could rewrite your code in the following manner:

```py
    # Old
    output = tf.conv3d(input, *other_args)

    # New
    output = tf.keras.layers.Conv3D(*other_args)(input)
```